# Visual Studio 2015 www local project only showing Hello World

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a basic Aurelia app using VS2015.  I was able to properly jspm install all the files I needed and I created by app.js and app.html and index.html files but when I try to run the app to see my hardcoded text all I see is 'Hello World!' in my browser.  I try to change the text to anything else but it keeps coming back Hello World.  I followed the example from Scott Allen on PluralSight.  His pull sup fine but I cannot.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  How do I get my index.html and not whatever is showing the Hello World text?  My table structure is as such

```
Solution
    |_Solution Items
      |_ global.json
    |_src
      |_ Demo
        |_ Properties
        |_ References
        |_ wwwroot
           |_ jspm_packages
           |_ app.html
           |_ app.js
           |_ index.html
           |_ config.js
        |_ Dependencies
        |_ package.json
        |_ project.json
        |_ Startup.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an ASP.NET V5 application you may not have set the solution to be able to serve static files.

In the startup.cs there is a configure method where you will need to enable using static files. My configure method ending up looking like this in order to work.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
 }
```

In the project.json I also had to add a dependency of

"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"